# post-require hook in php composer not working when installing from packagist.org

Tags: php, composer-php, hook

One can install PHP packages from packagist.org with a command such as `composer require vendor/package-name`. Now the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) states that there are hooks for several events during composer execution:

> A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) or any command-line executable command. Scripts are useful for executing a package's custom code or package-specific commands during the Composer execution process.

The doc further state:

**Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts.**

Does this mean there is no way to execute PHP code while a package is required from packagist.org via `composer require vendor/package-name`?

Comment: Only if you put manually a post script in your main composer.json before require the package. So you have no access to the root as package maintainer which would be a security problem if you can load and execute anything outside your package.

Answer (score 0):

There was a fairly long discussion about this topic in the `composer` issue-queue a few years ago.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1193

**TLDR**: It's not supported for `post-update-cmd` hooks, but it is possible to get around this by writing `composer` plugins. For example, I did a generic plugin to run a `compile` hook for any new or changed packages:

https://github.com/civicrm/composer-compile-plugin

An example from the docs:

```yaml
{
  "name": "foo/bar",
  "require": {
    "civicrm/composer-compile-plugin": "~0.8",
    "scssphp/scssphp": "1.2.0",
    "padaliyajay/php-autoprefixer": "~1.2"
  },
  "autoload": {"psr-4": {"ScssExample\\": "src"}},
  "extra": {
    "compile": [
      {"run": "@php-method \\ScssExample\\ScssExample::make"}
    ]
  }
}
```

And the corresponding callback:

```php
namespace ScssExample;
class ScssExample
{
  public static function make(array $task)
  {
    $scssCompiler = new \ScssPhp\ScssPhp\Compiler();
    $scss = 'div { .foo { hyphens: auto; } }';
    $css = $scssCompiler->compile($scss);
    $autoprefixer = new \Padaliyajay\PHPAutoprefixer\Autoprefixer($css);
    file_put_contents("build.css", $autoprefixer->compile());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

composer will dispatch a `post-update-cmd` event after installing the requested package with `require`. This will execute scripts defined in your root `composer.json` for this event. See this sample scenario:

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "fknffa\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "fknffa\\floom::sayHello"
        ]
    }
}
```

src/floom.php

```
<?php
namespace fknffa;

class floom
{

    public static function sayHello()
    {
        print 'I am in ' . __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Execute require command

```
$ composer require twig/twig
Using version ^1.23 for twig/twig
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.23.1)

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> fknffa\floom::sayHello
I am in fknffa\floom::sayHello
```

Comment: This is not working. Added `"scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "php src/notify.php"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php src/notify.php"
        ]
    },` to my composer.json file and pushed a new annotated tag to packagist.org and requried the module. No hooks are executed upon `composer require vendor/package-name`...

Comment: @Nikolai Tschacher I updated my answer, sorry for being late.

Comment: Just to clarify, the package being required isn't the root package (so the scripts won't execute)... the root package is the one from which you're executing the require cmd from.  *sad trombone*

Comment: So there is no way to execute scripts of a package when is being installed?